# How do I add a plugin to Custom Menu by Evolonix?

Tags: wordpress

The site I'm on is using Custom Menu from Evolonix http://evolonix.com/wordpress/plugins/custom-menu/

How do I add a plugin into the menu hierarchy?

For example, the url hierarchy is going to be:

```
Home (page)
About (page)
Resources (page)
    Support (page)
    Q & A  (plugin!)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Custom Menu plugin is a shortcode that renders any Menu you have created in your site. To change what pages are displayed in the custom menu, update the menu it is tied to by going to Appearance -> Menus. There, you can add a custom link to the menu that points to the Q & A plugin's page.

To see what menu the custom menu is tied to, edit the page or post that the menu is on. You should see the shortcode [menu name="xxx"... where xxx is the menu name.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Does wordpress have a "base url" function that I can call in the custom link field?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if it is a root domain, you can just start your link with / (e.g. /your-plugin-page) instead of having it start with http://. If it is in a subdirectory like 'wordpress' you can do /wordpress/your-plugin-page.